# Is the following embedding of $k5$ on torus not a 2-cell embedding? If not, how can we get the 2-cell embedding of $k5$ on the torus?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

[image]
I suspect it is not as the biggest face does not look like homeomorphic to a disk. But how can we modify the diagram to get 2-cell embedding?